# Adding extra field from other Model into Modelform along with giving attr

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm making Modelform for custom doors ordering platform and i would like to insert additional field from different Model into my Modelform in order to use it's value to insert it as new attribute.

So, this is how it looks like:

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Door(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
    excluded = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="", blank=True, null=False)


class Order(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=False)
   door = models.ForeignKey('Door', verbose_name=u"Type", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1, blank=False, null=True)
...
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import Door, Order

class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['door',]

        #adding additional class using widgets
        widgets = {
          'door': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={
          'class': 'radioselect'
        }),
...
```

**index.html**

```
<form id="d_form" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ ord_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Order" class="btn btn-danger">
</form>
```

**Rendered output**:

```
<li>
    <label for="id_door_1"><input type="radio" name="door" value="2" class="radioselect" required id="id_door_1">some option
    </label>
</li>
```

Everything renders properly, hovewer i would like to add extra new attr into radio input containing it's value, based on field **excluded=ITS VALUE** from **Door** model.

**Expected render**:

```
<li>
    <label for="id_door_1"><input type="radio" excluded='ITS VALUE' name="door" value="2" class="radioselect" required id="id_door_1">some option
    </label>
</li>
```

How to insert it?

Comment: instead of `ord_form.as_p` you can render the field individually, and for your [radio select](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect) field, loop over each option and render the `<input>` field manually.

Comment: alternatively, you subclass [`RadioSelect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect), and replace the **option_template_name** with your own template (copy the original one and modify it to include the `excluded` attribute).